# CloudFlare set-cookie not passing through to browser

Tags: express, cloudflare, passport.js, passport-local, express-session

I have an express application behind CloudFlare. In development, the Set-Cookie header gets passed on login, but behind CloudFlare, the Set-Cookie header is not passed. Any suggestions? My config is:

```
    import passport from 'passport';
    import cookieParser from 'cookie-parser';
    import session from 'express-session';
    import { Strategy as LocalStrategy } from 'passport-local';
    import localPassport from '../../db/sequelize/passport';

```
const secret = 'foo';

const authenticationMiddleware = (req, res, next) => {
  console.log('authenticated', req.isAuthenticated());

  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    next();
  } else if (req.url.includes('/rest/')) {
    res.status(401).send('Unauthorized');
  } else {
    res.status(302).redirect('/admin/login');
  }
};

const sessionSecurity = (app) => {
  app.set('trust proxy', 1);
  app.use(cookieParser(secret));
  app.use(
    session({
      secret,
      proxy: true, 
      saveUninitialized: false,
      resave: false,
      maxAge: null,
      cookie: {
        path: '/admin',
        secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
      },
    }),
  ); // session secret
  app.use(passport.initialize());
  app.use(passport.session());

  passport.use(new LocalStrategy(localPassport.local));
  passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    done(null, user.id);
  });
  passport.deserializeUser(localPassport.deserializeUser);

  app.post('/admin/login', (req, res, next) => {
    passport.authenticate('local', (authErr, user) => {
      if (authErr) return next(new Error(authErr));
      if (!user) {
        return res.sendStatus(401);
      }
      return req.logIn(user, (loginErr) => {
        if (loginErr) return res.sendStatus(401);
        return res.sendStatus(200);
      });
    })(req, res, next);
  });

  app.post('/admin/logout', (req, res) => {
    req.logOut();

    req.session.destroy(() => {
      res
        .clearCookie('connect.sid', { path: '/admin' })
        .sendStatus(200);
    });
  });

  app.get('/admin/rest/*', authenticationMiddleware);

  app.get('/admin/rest/status', (req, res) => {
    res.sendStatus(200);
  });

};
```

```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was caused because the server settings where set to cookie secure and the connection between CloudFlare and my server were not.

Comment: Hi. I have a same problem.so what is solution?

Answer (score 0):

In setting of cloudflare (crypto tab), I turned on "Authenticated Origin Pulls" and in "app.js" (from my app) add this `app.set('trust proxy', 1);`
before `app.use(session({...})` and my problem solved.